# Is there a way to use string.ascii_lowercase[:x], with x as user input?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question is how I can take a letter as input, convert it to its alphabetic number accordingly (0-26 for a-z) and use it in string.ascii_lowercase[:x] in order to print the alphabet up to this letter.

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase[:string.ascii_lowercase.find(x)+1]`?

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase[:ord('x')-96]` will print alphabets up to `'x'`

Comment: yes! thank you Roseman, go ahead and add it as an answer.

Comment: Same to you Dutta, thank you :)